# Can I update/reconfigure my AT&T Uverse 2Wire 3801HGV Gateway to use a different ISP?

Tags: modem, gateway

I recently received a used 3801HGV Uverse router from a relative. It appears it was manufactured by AT&T and has its firmware. I am attempting to replace my old mikrotik modem with it, but I can't seem to get it to connect to the ISP, and the only manual I found that shows how to set it up uses different firmware, and the options for the method it uses aren't accessible on the AT&T firmware.

How do I get this gateway to work with my non-AT&T ISP? Do I need to update the firmware, and if so, how do I do that?

I'm not entirely sure this is the correct Stack Exchange subdomain to post this in, and if it isn't please point me to the correct one.

Comment: Problem 1 is probably to get the ISP to recognise the MAC address of your new router ...

Comment: Yeah but most ISP's let you login, and if not then all it takes is a quick call. One may even be able to change the MAC to the same one as the previous modem, i'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: Indeed, so that should be your first step.